# Custom ADO.Net Data Provider - How To?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Is there any good How-To document on developing Custom ADO.Net data provider?

I looked at the MSDN and all I could find is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ksaf9z5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) published on this subject in 2003 and could not find any update for later versions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: May I ask for what database you need it for ?

Comment: Sungard Investran. I am trying to build an ADO.Net Provider on top of their COM API. This is necessity as their OLEDB provider is having issues working with SSIS & SSRS, but their COM API is pretty stable. However I need to go thru a lot of steps if I need to use it directly. So thought that building an ADO.Net Data Provider might simplify things little bit.

Answer (score 1):

That's still all there is to it if you are using basic ADO.Net.  The API is pretty stable.